# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. how can I solved this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MongoDB, Express JS , Node JS